# How to create a range in SQL with string so I can use as a condition to exclude? Ex. Select data where it excludes A1 - A999

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have a column in the database that has the first letter as string and the rest is number. I would select the data where it excludes only the A1 -> A999, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Exclude? Prevent insert, or not select?

Comment: I am using Spark SQL and also I would like to exclude on select statement

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
SELECT
FROM
...
WHERE
LEFT(column,1) != 'A'
```

OR

```
column NOT LIKE 'A%'
```

Comment: That only works if I would like to exclude A, but what if I want data that are less than or greater than. Ex. if the condition is to exclude A100 - A300, I want to select data that have less than A100 and greater than A300.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `check` constraint.  Assuming that the column always has the format you specify:

```
alter table t add constraint chk_t_col
    check (col >= 'A999')
```

If you want only value *in* that range, then use:

```
alter table t add constraint chk_t_col
    check (col >= 'A001' and col <= 'A999')
```